# Is gradient descent scale invariant or not?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I know we should scale the input and output (assuming regression task) before we feed it to the neural network. Then the gradient descent will give the better minima much faster. But I have subtle confusion whether gradient descent with feature scale and without feature scale gives the same result or just gradient descent is not scale-invariant.

Answer (score 3):

Gradient descent is *not* scale invariant *by and large*.

That is because the step-size (i.e. our movement along the gradient direction) is often fixed but the curvature of the loss function being explored is dependent on the scale of the input values. So for example, we will very likely require different numbers of steps to arrive at a minimum and/or arrive in different (global or local) minima *values*. That said, these minima will occur for qualitatively the same point $x_{opt}$ as any observed differences will be due to rescaling.

Comment: @user11852 I don't understand this line "That said, these minima will occur for qualitatively the same point $x_{opt}$ as any observed differences will be due to rescaling." Can you explain it again, please?

Comment: Sure thing. Say we have scaled our input values and we minimise $f(z)=z^2$, $z_{opt}$ is obviously $0$, starting at $z=1$  we do $n_z$ step to get there. Now say we have our original unscaled version of our values such that $2x=z$ minimising this now will mean we are minimise $f(x) = 4x^2$, $x_{opt}$ if obviously $0$ again but the curvature of our function is larger; starting from $x=1$ we do $n_x$ step to get there but most likely $n_x  < n_z$. You will correctly note that in this case $x=1$ is closer to the optimum $0$ that $z=1$  and that is exactly why grad.descent is not scale invariant.

Comment: @user11852 But if think of a large number of iteration, then I converge to the same point for the aforementioned example.

Comment: Yes, of course they do. :) As I said, it is "*and/or*"; in this super short example it is the number of steps that is different but not different minima values. Assume thought that we had $2x+1=z$ than we would change our curvature and the location of the minima.